# Поставить принудительно пробел в конце текста в texteare JS

Tags: javascript

Сабж в названии :) всем заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let value = ELEMENT.value + " a";
```

Это строка для примера, если ты а удалишь то добавишь только пробел

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ELEMENT = document.getElementById("aloha");
  let value = ELEMENT.value + " a";
  ELEMENT.value = value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="aloha">aloha</textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Дякую велике :)